# Get changing items in JSON using PHP

Tags: php, json

So, I have the following JSON:

```
"response": {
    "status": 1,
    "httpStatus": 200,
    "data": {
      "16322": {
        "SignupAnswer": {
          "id": "16322",
          "question_id": "4",
          "responder_type": "affiliate",
          "answer": "https://www.hoopladoopla.com",
          "responder_user_id": null,
          "ref_id": null,
          "responder_id": "3532",
          "modified": "2014-03-26 13:00:23",
          "question": "URL de tu sitio web",
          "type": "affiliate",
          "status": "active"
        }
      }
```

I need to get response->data->16322, and turn the information inside those into php variables so I can save them into an SQL database, but I need some general rule to do it without specifying the last item's name since it will change constantly.

It is very likely that I am not making myself clear at all (since I don't know what I'm looking for, only the result), but I hope someone will understand where I'm going and find a way to do this.

Any ideas?

Comment: use json_decode on the above result, which will return you an associative array. Then print_R($array), and look at the resulting array structure and then access the data in it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as

```
$j = '{"response": {
    "status": 1,
    "httpStatus": 200,
    "data": {
      "16322": {
        "SignupAnswer": {
          "id": "16322",
          "question_id": "4",
          "responder_type": "affiliate",
          "answer": "https://www.hoopladoopla.com",
          "responder_user_id": null,
          "ref_id": null,
          "responder_id": "3532",
          "modified": "2014-03-26 13:00:23",
          "question": "URL de tu sitio web",
          "type": "affiliate",
          "status": "active"
        }
      }
     }
    }
}';

$data = json_decode($j,true);

foreach($data["response"]["data"] as $key=>$val){
  // $val will hold the data for the key and can do a loop to get the elements and data
  // $key will be 16322 and it could be anything which is assigned to $key
  print_r($val); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid JSON, it is missing some `{` and `}`, but if it was:

```
$array = json_decode($data, true);
$result = reset($array['response']['data']);
print_r($result);
```

Or PHP >= 5.4.0

```
$result = reset(json_decode($data, true)['response']['data']);
```

Or if there are multiple entries for `data`, then:

```
foreach(json_decode($data, true)['response']['data'] as $key => $array) {
    //do something with $array['id'] or whatever
}
```